# Skipping to the beginning of a for loop in a Scala program

Tags: java, scala

In a for loop in my Scala code, i want to skip to the beginning of the loop and not execute following statements if a particular condition is true. In Java i can use 'continue' for doing this. But 'continue' does not seem to work in Scala.
So how can i skip to the beginning of my loop in a Scala program ?

Please Help
Thank You.

Comment: Can you explain your use-case for this?  It's almost guaranteed that there's a better solution for you that doesn't involve loops at all.

Comment: I bet the OP can be achieved using a `if` guard in `for` comprehension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Scala 2.7, from http://www.scala-lang.org/node/257

> These keywords are not included in Scala 2.7, and must be implemented in a different way. For break, the simplest thing to do is to divide your code into smaller methods and use the return to exit early. For continue, a simple approach is to place the skipped-over parts of a loop into an if.
>   Scala 2.8 will include break, but not continue.

If you're using Scala 2.8

```
import util.control.Breaks._
// for continue, write this somewhere in your program
val continue = new Breaks
/* use like */
Breaks.breakable {
  for (i <- 1 to 10)
  continue.breakable { if (i % 2 == 0) continue.break; println(i); if (i == 7) Breaks.break }
}


//source http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/04/breaks.html
```

Note that normally needing `break` and `continue` means that you aren't being as functional as Scala would like you to be.

Answer (score 7):

First, your best option is usually to avoid that sort of construct anyway, and try to use higher-level methods instead (e.g. you can often do `xs.map(doSomeStuff).filter(condition).foreach(doConditionalStuff)`).  This isn't always practical, but it is far more often than you might initially suspect.  Still, the issue remains for those cases where continue is useful: a very long series of guards within a long code block that cannot be logically broken into pieces.

`continue` is a difficult language construct for a language with anonymous functions.  One reason is practical: the anonymous function is a function, and you can't easily go back to some loop that's calling it just by executing a jump.  Another reason is conceptual: if you're in a `map` method, which itself is a kind of loop, where exactly should the `continue` take you back to the beginning of?

Rather than dealing with these awkward cases, Scala provides (as a library function, based upon exceptions) a `breakable` construct that explicitly specifies where you want to break to:

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks._
breakable {
  for (i <- 1 to 10) {
    if (i>3) break
    println(i)
  }
}
```

But because this is a generic construct, you can use it inside the for loop also:

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks._
for (i <- 1 to 10) {
  breakable {
    if ((i%2)==0) break
    println(i)
  }
}
```

You can even break to multiple levels if you create your own break classes.  Here's an example of simulating a for loop with both break and continue:

```
val outer,inner = new scala.util.control.Breaks
outer.breakable {
  for (i <- 1 to 10) {
    inner.breakable {
      if ((i%2)==0) inner.break
      if (i>3) outer.break
      println(i)
    }
  }
}
```

And if you use this pattern a lot, you can change your imports to make it nicer:

```
// Do this once at the top of the file
import scala.util.control.Breaks._
object Continued extends scala.util.control.Breaks {}
import Continued.{break=>continue, breakable=>continuing}

// Now every time you need it:
breakable{ for (i <- 1 to 10) continuing {
  if ((i%2)==0) continue
  if (i>3) break
  println(i)
}}
```

It is a bit more work to type if you *really* need that functionality, but given how nonsensical breaks and continues are in the context of the *other* very useful functionality that Scala has, it's not a bad compromise.